# Perl WebService::Soundcloud - how to pass track parameters while uploading to Soundcloud

Tags: perl, soundcloud

I'm trying to upload a sound to soundcloud using `WebService::Soundcloud`. I've so far been able to make a couple of GET/POST requests following the examples provided by [the `WebService::Soundcloud` documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~mpgutta/WebService-Soundcloud-0.01/lib/WebService/Soundcloud.pm).

However, I can't find a decent example anywhere on how to do an upload while passing the required parameters i.e. track, and within it, asset_data, title e.t.c. I'm wondering if I should be sending out a multipart message.

Any examples will be appreciated!

Also, here's what I have tried so far: After authenticating and getting a valid `WebService::Soundcloud` instance.

```
GET my $response = $scloud->get( '/me/tracks' );
PUT my $response = $scloud->put( '/me/tracks/91576621', JSON::to_json({track=>{title=>"My test title",description=>"My test description"}}) );
POST my $file = '/home/ski/track1.mp3';
my $asset_data = File::Slurp::read_file( $file, binmode => ':raw' );
my $response = $scloud->post('/me/tracks', '{"track":{"title":"My test title","asset_data":"'.$asset_data.'"}}' );
```

This fails with "Request entity contains invalid byte sequence. Please transmit valid UTF-8"

Comment: Any code examples of what you've done so far (e.g. the GET/POST requests)?

Comment: After authenticating and getting a valid `WebService::Soundcloud` instance.

GET

`my $response = $scloud->get( '/me/tracks' );`

PUT

`my $response = $scloud->put( '/me/tracks/91576621', JSON::to_json({track=>{title=>"My test title",description=>"My test description"}}) );
`
POST

`my $file = '/home/ski/track1.mp3';
my $asset_data = File::Slurp::read_file( $file, binmode => ':raw' );
my $response = $scloud->post('/me/tracks', '{"track":{"title":"My test title","asset_data":"'.$asset_data.'"}}' );`

This fails with "Request entity contains invalid byte sequence. Please transmit valid UTF-8"

Comment: Is that the full error message, or is there more to it? I don't know the Soundcloud API and have worked with neither `WebService::Soundcloud` nor `JSON::to_json` - but could it be that the problem is in the syntax for the `JSON::to_json`. Have you tried using `encode_json()` instead, as does the `WebService::Soundcloud` documentation for PUT requests?

Comment: @thunk That is all there is in `$response->content()`. And i did try `encode_json()` as well as just writing the json string myself. Thats probably not the issue since the `PUT` example above works just fine with `JSON::to_json`.

Comment: Well, that's all the ideas I had. I guess without time to spend on looking at that package, I can't help you any further. Let's hope somebody else who has used it before can help! Or otherwise, maybe try one of the languages where [Souncloud provides an SDK](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks)?!?

Comment: Thanks for your responses! its gotta be in perl, i'm working on a much bigger project that is built entirely in perl.

Answer (score 0):

The example you provide manually constructs the JSON but doesn't take into account the binary nature of the file content which means it's unlikely to work. It's also *vulnerable* to abusive content changing your JSON due to lack of escaping/proper encoding.

The documentation you cite has a **put** example which demonstrate the content needs to be encoded into JSON and then passed to the library. I've not used this api but it's probably a simple case of using **encode_json** as per the examples. I'll just show an example that's equivalent to your manual encoding:

```
use JSON qw(encode_json);

my $asset_data = "ascii, quotes (\"'), non-ascii: \000\001\002\003";

my $content =  encode_json({ track => { title => "My test title",
                                    asset_data => $asset_data}});

print $content . "\n";  ### inspection of encoding
```

And this shows that JSON uses a UTF-8 representation to deal with binary data:

```
{"track":{"asset_data":"ascii, quotes (\"'), non-ascii: \u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003","title":"My test title"}}
```

The key/values are being re-ordered there but it's equivalent JSON.